# Email Attachments Not making it through

Tags: c#, email

I have a c# program that uses a fileuploader control to collect a path to a file name for attachment to an email. When I run the webpage with an attachment in debug, all is fine and the email comes with an attachment. However, when I deploy it to a server, the email makes it through but the attachment does not.

```
MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
    message.To.Add("test1@test.com");
    message.Subject = "Project Created";
    message.From = new MailAddress("noreply@test.com");
    message.Body = "You have recieved a project request from " + TxtContactName.Text + " Project Name: " + TxtProjectName.Text + " Priority: " + DDLPriority.SelectedValue.ToString() + " Business Area: " + DDLBusinessArea.SelectedValue.ToString();

    if (FileUpload1.FileName.Length > 0)
    {
        if (File.Exists(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName))
            message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName));
    }

    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("PMFex02");
    NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential();
    cred.UserName = "test@test.com";
    cred.Password = "test";
    cred.Domain = "test.com";

    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

    smtp.Send(message);
```

I have tried it with and without the credentials set, but it behaves the same way.
Any idea why the attachment won't make it through when deployed to a server?

Comment: Antivirus on the mail server?

Comment: Other attachments are able to get through from internal and external sources

Comment: That doesn't mean yours won't get removed.

Comment: But my code running in debug is using the same smtp server as when run directly from the server. Wouldn't it get knocked off either way?

Comment: Not necessarily, all depends on how the mail server is set up. There may be exceptions in place when connections are coming in from a different IP address for example.

Comment: We have been researching this and the anti virus is not the issue. It allows other email attachments through the system, just not those generated by my application. We have also installed the web app on IIS 7 now and there is no difference. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure the email is being attached in the first place? Have you put some logging in to check what is happening in your code? PS Are you the real Rigamonk? :)

Answer (score 0):

Add some extra content to your message Subject or Body to see how far into the attachment you get:

```
MailMessage message = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
message.To.Add("test1@test.com");
message.Subject = "Project Created";
message.From = new MailAddress("noreply@test.com");
message.Body = "You have recieved a project request from " + TxtContactName.Text + " Project Name: " + TxtProjectName.Text + " Priority: " + DDLPriority.SelectedValue.ToString() + " Business Area: " + DDLBusinessArea.SelectedValue.ToString();

if (FileUpload1.FileName.Length > 0)
{
  message.Subject .= string.Format(" ({0} bytes)", FileUpload1.FileName.Length);
  if (File.Exists(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName))
  {
    message.Subject .= " E";
    message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName));
  }
}
```

It may only make sense to you, but if it gets left on there it won't hurt either.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you aren't actually authenticating with your credentials, which would likely cause attachments to be dropped in spam filter. Try this:

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("PMFex02");

NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential();
cred.UserName = "test@test.com";
cred.Password = "test";
cred.Domain = "test.com";

smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
smtp.Credentials = cred;
smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
smtp.Send(message);
```

You may also want to add an `smtp.Timeout` value higher than the default, possibly with a guard against files considered too large.